# Tornado demo chat, template messages

Tags: chat, tornado

I learn tornado. Picking their demo chat, maybe anybody can explain to me this:
Template variable -messages

class MainHandler(BaseHandler):
    @tornado.web.authenticated
    def get(self):
        self.render("index.html", messages=MessageMixin.cache)

Template:

<div id="inbox">
        {% for message in messages %}
          {% module Template("message.html", message=message) %}
        {% end %}
      </div>

This is a users' messages in chat, but they are inserted via javascript.
If you remove template variable messages, then everything works fine too.
Why in the template, this variable?

Comment: This is a cache is written in earlier posts.

Answer (score 2):

The MessageMixin.cache gives you the list of last N messages (200 by default), that was sent **before** you opened the page, so they are rendered by Tornado on server side. While javascript is used to render messages, which were sent **after** you opened the page.